# Swift: error: use of undeclared type 'T'

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

Swift 3.0 and getting this error, unsure why:

Code:

```
func rest(_ list: ArraySlice<T>) -> ArraySlice<T> {
    return list.dropFirst()
}
```

Error:

```
error: repl.swift:1:48: error: use of undeclared type 'T'
func rest(_ list: ArraySlice<T>) -> ArraySlice<T> {
                                               ^
```

Comment: There's no `ArrayList` type in Swift Standard Library, where and how do you declare it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `func rest(_ list: Array<Int>) -> Array<Int> {`

Comment: Strange that you would expect java to work in Swift...

Comment: My mistake guys!! I was trying something right before I pasted the problem... and copied and pasted the wrong thing

Comment: `func rest<T: Integer>(_ list: ArraySlice<T>) -> ArraySlice<T> {
    return list.dropFirst()
}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify the generic parameter of `ArraySlice`, just using as `ArraySlice<T>` does not declare `T`:

```
func rest<T>(_ list: ArraySlice<T>) -> ArraySlice<T> {
    return list.dropFirst()
}
```

Or:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    func rest(_ list: ArraySlice<T>) -> ArraySlice<T> {
        return list.dropFirst()
    }
}
```